# Looping through a list and changing data into tables

Tags: excel, vba

Beginner VBA here. As part of a larger macro, I am bringing in sheets from another workbook after an earlier process is done (I have finished this part), but I then want to change the data brought in into tables. Because there are hundreds of tabs in this workbook, I think having a list of tab names to do a loop through would be the easiest option. I have the below but cannot seem to get it to work. I think the only thing I am missing is to activate whatever sheet it is selecting. (There will be more than A1:A2, I am just using a smaller range to test):

```
Sub TabstoTables()

    Dim tablename As Range
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each tablename In Sheets("Tab Names").Range("A1:A2")

        Set rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
        Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
        tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"

    Next tablename
End Sub
```

Appreciate any help!! Thanks so much

Comment: Explicitly give the `Range` objects a worksheet, otherwise it's going to use the `Range()` on the `ActiveSheet`, whatever that may be.  So, I assume your ranges are all on the sheet "Tab Names" - add `Worksheets("Tab Names").` before each `Range()` call:  `Worksheets("Tab Names").Range(Worksheets("Tab Names").Range("A1"), Worksheets("Tab Names").Range("A1")...`  (You can of course use a `With` statement to make that shorter)

Comment: Thanks so much that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with a few changes:

```
Sub TabstoTables()

    Dim tablename As Variant
    Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range       

    For Each tablename In Sheets("Tab Names").Range("A1:A2")
        Set TargetSheet = Worksheets(CStr(tablename))
        Set rng = Range(TargetSheet.Range("A1"), TargetSheet.Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
        Set tbl = TargetSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
        tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"     
    Next tablename
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, appreciate all the help! I was having the error that BruceWayne mentioned above..just needed it to reference the actual sheet I wanted. Appreciate it

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use this on the full range and am getting "subscript out of range" error for line: Set TargetSheet = Worksheets(CStr(tablename)). Any idea on how to fix this?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub TabstoTables()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range

On Error GoTo Err
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        rng = sht.UsedRange
        Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes)
        tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium15"
    Next sht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Err:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "There was an error"
End Sub
```

You can iterate through the Sheets themselves and not have to have the list of sheet names.

Also, notice the "On Error" and the code following "Err:".  This handles resetting Application.ScreenUpdating = True if there is an error in your process.  With the way your code is currently written, if it failed somewhere along the line, your ScreenUpdating would be stuck at False and now you're in a really bad state.

Comment: Thank you! There are over 300 tabs on here, not counting the ones that I would need to bring over so it would be a lot to cycle through all the tabs. This is great to know for those cases that I would need that